# How to rewrite this function to a interface?

Tags: typescript, react-native

My goal is to write everything in interface, TypeScript. It's for React Native.

This is the function I am unable to put into an interface. The current solution is to put it outside the interface but the import would be ugly e.g import AudioRecorderModule, { addAudioRecorderEventListener } from '...'

```
export const addAudioRecorderEventListener = (
  listener: (data: number[]) => void,
) => eventEmitter.addListener('read', listener);
```

AudioRecorder.module.ts

```
import {NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules} from 'react-native';

import AudioRecorderInterface from './AudioRecorder.d';

const {AudioRecorderModule} = NativeModules;

const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(AudioRecorderModule);

export const addAudioRecorderEventListener = (
  listener: (data: number[]) => void,
) => eventEmitter.addListener('read', listener);

export default AudioRecorderModule as AudioRecorderInterface;
```

AudioRecorder.d.ts

```
export default interface AudioRecorderInterface {
  startAudioRecordingAsync(): Promise<null>;
  stopAudioRecordingAsync(): Promise<null>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you are importing from a `.d.ts`.  You should put your interface in the `.ts` file and let the the `.d.ts` be generated when you `build` your code.

In order to call `new NativeEventEmitter(AudioRecorderModule)`, the module has to implement the `EventSubscriptionVendor` interface.

I think this code answers your question:

```
interface AudioRecorderInterface {
  startAudioRecordingAsync(): Promise<null>;
  stopAudioRecordingAsync(): Promise<null>;
  addAudioRecorderEventListener(listener: (data: number[]) => void): EmitterSubscription;
}

const AudioRecorderModule = NativeModules.AudioRecorderModule as AudioRecorderInterface & EventSubscriptionVendor;

const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(AudioRecorderModule);

AudioRecorderModule.addAudioRecorderEventListener = (
  listener: (data: number[]) => void,
) => eventEmitter.addListener('read', listener);

export default AudioRecorderModule;
```

But be aware that when we use `as AudioRecorderInterface & EventSubscriptionVendor`, we are telling typescript that the module must implement those interfaces.  You will have problems if the module doesn't actually implement those methods.

Comment: I think I made mistake on how `d.ts` should work. I also tried your solution `const AudioRecorderModule = NativeModules.AudioRecorderModule as AudioRecorderInterface & EventSubscriptionVendor;`. The `new NativeEventEmitter()` only accepts parameter with `NativeModule` type.

Comment: I found it interesting you do this `AudioRecorderModule.addAudioRecorderEventListener = (data => void) => eventEmitter.addListener()` I will try it tonight or tomorrow morning. Is this the recommended way for TypeScript to invoke method or is this hacky `seems hacky to me`? Anyway, thank you! I will mark this as solution tomorrow morning, it does looks like to be the solution.

Comment: To be honest I don't have much experience working with `NativeModules`.  I'm good at identifying TS errors in general so I can see what the types need to be, but I don't know what `AudioRecorderModule` actually is.  The `NativeModules` object in react-native is typed very loosely such that the properties have type `any` when you access them:  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/78d3871eaac015aa1e7093327ed654832315cae7/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L9722  I am using `as` to assert the correct type, but maybe you could extend the react-native `NativeModulesStatic` type.

Comment: I'm adding `addAudioRecorderEventListener` as a property on the `AudioRecorderModule` object which...is probably ok?  But again I don't know what `AudioRecorderModule` actually looks like.  I'm just asserting what it needs to look like in order for your code to work.